# unable to SSH into Azure Ubuntu VM after reboot

Tags: azure

I have been using this VM (Azure ubuntu) for almost a month but had to restart to increase the disk size which was successful. I have preserved the IP address. But now unable to SSH. I also "reset configuration only" from the "Reset Password option". Also tried "test connection" within Azure Portal and that fails as well. But I am still able to access MySQL database which is running on the same VM. What am I doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: Hello @Svj, may i know what error messages are you getting while trying to SSH?

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT - when is clicked test connection within Azure portal i get this. "Failed to start deployment. There was an error provisioning the resource group 'NetworkWatcherRG'." I am able to access mysql but NO ssh.

Comment: hello @Svj , Testconnection is for Network Watcher , if you have network watcher enabled for the specific region where the VM's Vnet is located then it will check the connection on a specfic port. and if not enabled then it will error out. can you please try using putty or any other SSH clients for the connecting the VM and let me know what error you are receiving there.

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT - both putty and vscode displays "connection timed out"

Comment: can you please add both the error screenshots  to the question ? and please check the NSG rules for the VM ..

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT - thanks for your reply. added the screenshot for reference.

Comment: Can you see IP address you are connectig is the same in overview?

Comment: @VovaBilyachat i do have static public IP. I can still access the MySQL but not SSH.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, it worked. All I had to do was a reset via the CLI:

```
az vm user reset-ssh --resource-group myresourcegroup --name myvm
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/vmaccess